What does the "Enhan. Campaign" checkbox do?
In the mobile game Nier Reincarnation, when looking at characters or weapons in the Enhance menu, what does the "Enhan. Campaign" checkbox do? How does it affect which characters are shown?
Enhan. Campaign checked

Enhan. Campaign unchecked


In Japanese version that checkbox is called "編成中優先", which means priority show the character that is in deck, but I don't know if that's true for global version, since your screenshot does contain that is not in a deck that is showed up earlier than the character that is in deck. Could you toggle on and off to check if that applies?

@Skye-AT Edited question to include screenshots of the option toggled on and off.

Hmm, it seems to be unchecking the box doing the thing. This is my speculation, but maybe checking the box will priority show the character that is enhanceable?
